# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/myname/PycharmProjects/sensorLogProject/Data/PickUpPhoneAccelerometer1.csv'

Tags: python, file, csv, path, pycharm

I get that error with the following script:

```
with open(os.path.join("Users", "myname", "PycharmProjects",
           "sensorLogProject", "Data", f), 'rU') as my_file:
```

Even though when I use PyCharm to get the path, it returns:

```
/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/sensorLogProject/Data/PickUpPhoneAccelerometer1.csv
```

Edit: /Data is a Python Package not a directory if that helps

Comment: Do you suppose the first character is significant?

Comment: Could you check the last edit? I believe that might be the issue.

Comment: I don't notice any change. The string on the error message differs from the path in your question by one character. Do you think that character is important?

Comment: Actually, you are correct. I needed to add the first character

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(os.path.join("/Users", "myname", "PycharmProjects",
       "sensorLogProject", "Data", f), 'rU') as my_file:
```

I was missing the first character.